# Why will similar mysql query not execute?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP PDO with MYSQL

The following works

```
$customer = "2";
$ammount = "123.50";
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_customer,transaction_ammount) VALUES ($customer,$ammount)");
```

The following does not work

```
$biggy = "Jim";
$chum = "Tester";
$sql = $db->query("insert into customers(customer_firstname,customer_lastname,customer_telephone) values ($biggy,$chum,'7576632423');");
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: added but get no error message
    if (!$sql) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Answer (score 4):

Your first example works because you are working with numbers.

You need quotes around the strings in the 2nd SQL statement

```
$sql = $db->query("insert into customers(customer_firstname,customer_lastname,customer_telephone) values ('$biggy','$chum','7576632423');");
```

You can avoid pitfalls like this using PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and using prepared statements rather than writing SQL by hand. I highly recommend you look into it :)

Answer (score 3):

Strings need to be quoted.

```
... values ('$biggy','$chum','7576632423');");
```

You should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) too, though.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string and PDO ?

Comment: Yeah, avoid raw statements all together unless required. I was rather hoping they'd click, see the massive warning, and think again.